# How to structure NestJS monorepo and build application with relevant assets?

Tags: nestjs

## Situation

I am building a set of applications based on a [NestJS monorepo](https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/monorepo#monorepo-mode).

I have severals `apps` that relies on severals shared `libs`.

Those `apps` are similar to one another, but may still differ on some features, so the monorepo totally makes sense.

Some of the `libs` provides `@Controller()`, which `@Render()` views for common features.

### Assomptions

1. Template files should live in the module.
   Since there is a high coupling between the controller and the rendered template,
   I believe it makes sense to store the views template files (.hbs, .ejs, whatever) in the `libs` module providing the `@Controller`,
2. Only relevant templates should be shipped in dist/ when I build an app
   I have some business/legal/security constraints that force me to avoid the presence of some `libs` in some `apps` production environment.
   eg. `my-secret-algo-lib` should not be present in `my-public-unsecure-internet-app`

So it makes a file structure like this :

```
monorepo/
  apps/
    my-first-app/
       src/
          main.ts <-- nest bootstrap function is here
       ...
    my-second-app/
    ...

  libs/
    my-first-lib/
      src/
        my-first-lib.module.ts
        my-first-lib.controller.ts  <-- @Render('my-view')
        ...
      views/
         my-view.ejs <-- the view
   ...
```

### Goal

I want to achieve a build that produce the following file structure :

```
dist/
  apps/
    my-first-app/
       main.js
       views/
         my-first-lib/
           my-view.ejs
```

Assuming that:

- `my-first-app` imports `my-first-lib`
- Views that may exists in unused libs should not be included in `dist/`

## Questions

- Is this possible with existing tools?
- Would this be considered an anti-pattern? if so how should I structure things ?
- If the answer to both is "no", should I build something myself or join any existing effort?

Another part of the problem is NestJS application module configuration, but I guess this comes last...